# expand or collapse nested table rows in jsp. pagination is also needed

Tags: jquery, jsp, pagination, displaytag

im displaying a table with large number of rows in my jsp page using displaytags.

lets say each row in this table represents a shipment (like fedex shipments). According to a new requirement, i need to display the documents submitted for each shipment in an inner table nested under each row..and the results should still be paginated.

i have implemented the below approach
--- First load the shipments table and then get the documents in a seperate ajax request when the row is selected.---

but i want to get the shipments details and the documents details for each shipment in one collection and display them as rows in a table and still paginate..

how can i do this?

Comment: You can do it with javascript. The pagination may require Ajax.

Comment: @developerwjk i know that javascript and ajax need to be used.. could you be more specific as to how to approach this problem?